# Ansible Jinja Template config and stdout comparison

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

My pseudocode:
1. Get the ntp server config from "sh run"
2. Store that to a list
3. Jinja template generates the required config. I am passing the ntp_server IPs via -e (extra variables).
4. Add the config from 3, compare 3 and 4 and remove the rest.

I am struggling on step 4 [comparison part]. How do I compare the current config with the config generated from the jinja template? I am using roles.

Please advise.

```
# Jinja Template

    {% for ntp_srv in ntp_servers %}
    ntp server {{ ntp_srv }}
    {% endfor %}

# tasks file for ansible-ios-ntp
---
  - name: Current Edge servers before
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - sh run | include ntp server
    register: runconfser

  - debug:
      var: runconfser

  # NTP SECTION - START

  - name: Set NTP servers
    ios_config:
      src: ntprequired.j2
    notify: Save Config

  - name: Remove the rest NTP Servers
    with_items: "{{ runconfser.stdout_lines[0] }}"
    when: (item not in {src: 'ntprequired.j2'} and (item!=""))
    ios_config:
      lines:
        - "no {{ item }}"
```

Comment: Are you able to show what the output format is for `runconfser`?

Comment: Yes, the output of runconfser is:

        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                "ntp server 1.1.1.1",
                "ntp server 2.2.2.2"
            ]

Comment: I am going to assume you have a typo and `stdout_lines:` is just a list of strings, and not a list of list of strings

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you'd want to extract the current IPs from the registered output, then capture the ones which are not in the `ntp_servers` list:

```
  - set_fact:
     need_ips: |
        {{ ntp_servers | difference(stdout_lines | join(" ") | regex_findall('[0-9.]+')) }}
```

Or you can obtain the "extra" ones by inverting the order of the `difference`:

```
  - set_fact:
     extra_ips: |
        {{ stdout_lines | join(" ") | regex_findall('[0-9.]+') | difference(ntp_servers) }}
```

I cheated by just searching for `[0-9.]+` but you can, of course, make that expression less tolerant by being more specific (aka `[1-9](.[0-9.]){3}`)

Comment: I was actually trying to compare the configs generated in ntprequired.j2 with the running-config (variable: runconfser). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If I am understanding your followup question correctly, `- set_fact: foo: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/ntprequired.j2') }}"` will assign the _rendered_ Jinja template to a variable, after which you can then carry out that diffing process above